# Receving network request in JSON instead of XML in Corona

Tags: json, httprequest, coronasdk

I am doing a simple network request where I receive the results in XML format. Is there a way to receive the results in JSON format (or this is up to the server what format to respond)?

```
local function networkListener( event )

    if ( event.isError ) then
        print( "Network error!" )
    else
        print ( "RESPONSE: " .. event.response )
    end

    local saveData = event.response

local path = system.pathForFile( "myfile.txt", system.DocumentsDirectory )

local file = io.open( path, "w" )
file:write( saveData )

io.close( file )
file = nil
end

network.request( "http://www.carsales.com.au/cars/results?area=Stock&vertical=car&sortBy=TopDeal&q=(((Make%3D%5BToyota%5D)%26(Model%3D%5BCamry%5D))%26(Service%3D%5BCarsales%5D)%26(Year%3drange%5b2015..2015%5d))&WT.z_srchsrcx=makemodel/format=json", "GET", networkListener, params )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to be only dependent on the server. Some servers such as Google may allow JSON response but many other wont which is pretty stupid.

Answer (score 1):

A true REST service should let you specify JSON or XML to fetch the data.  However not all web based API's are fully RESTful and you are probably limited by what they service offers.

Rob